# Sending nest objects as Post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I'm trying to send this as my POST request to a express server:

```
{
    "name": "Turnê Estadual AngloGold Ashanti - Raposos/MG - The Beatles Vol. 2",
    "tour": "#D79B07",
    "date": "2020-05-17T00:00:00-03:00",
    "hour": {
        "start": "2020-05-17T18:00:00-03:00",
        "end": "2020-05-17T19:00:00-03:00",
    },
    "local": "Raposos/MG",
    "address": "",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-73.97, 40.77]
    },
    "duration": "70 minutos",
    "classification": "Livre",
    "description": "Em breve, mais informações."
}
```

and i'm getting this as an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 256<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br>`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Ailton, glad to have you here. Could you include the code you use for submitting. It most likely contains the issue

Comment: There's an extra comma at the `"end": "2020-05-17T19:00:00-03:00",` line - remove this comma.

Comment: This JSON are correct. Please tell us more details, e.g: This error happen in server ou browser?